# Label alignment to top when UIImage is nil Using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I am trying to designing dynamic UI , I trying to move label to the top sometimes when image view image will be empty using auto layout[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: adjusting your constraint.constant??

Comment: ya I can vary constraint constant .But I am trying to find out different ways dynamically,

Comment: That is the way I know, If you find some other way please let me know about

Answer (score 1):

Take IBOutlet of hight constant of image view.
Check programatically in cell for row if image is null then set constant to 0 otherwise whatever you set before.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a vertical UIStackView for the image and the label. The UIStackView will automatically align the elements the correct way.

At the end you could do the whole cell with stackviews:

```
UIStackView (vertical)
  UIStackView (horizontal)  // header
    UIImage                 // icon
    UIStackView (vertical)
      UIImage               // mAdvisor
      UILabel               // description
      UIView                // empty 'spacer' view
  UILabel                   // content
```

The 'spacer' view is needed to move the label to top if no image is provided.